# use drupal hook_nodeapi

Tags: drupal-6

i have a page tweety which contains a single form where a user enters a word in a textbox and in on pressing search the tweets corresponding to that word are displayed.

I want to use **hook_nodeapi** to add these tweets but i want those things only on a specific url not all the page(or any node type).

I ll use **hook_menu** to make that page and display the form for the search. What should i do after that. I knw the twiiter api to fetch the tweets so that is not a issue.

Comment: Please clarify: _but i want those things only on a specific url not all the page(or any node type)_

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're attempting to do is have the tweets load on a predetermined page by passing the posted information to the page, is that correct?

There's a couple ways I think you could accomplish this - easiest, and not requiring any complex ahah scripting would be to take the word they enter and generate a path which you could then use to make the page in question.

Make a menu Item:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
 $items = array();
 $items['mymodule/tweets/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('Tweets about' . check_plain(array(2))),
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_tweet_display',
  'page arguments' => array(2) // This is the 3rd argument in the path, the %
 );
}
```

In your form, you'll need to send the user to this path so add to your hook_submit function:

```
$tweet_topic = $form_state['values']['your-field-name-here'];
drupal_goto('mymodule/tweets/' . $tweet_topic);
```

Now add your page module, this is where you can use the twitter api:

```
function mymodule_tweet_display($tweet_topic) {
 $tweet_topic = check_plain($tweet_topic); 

 // Use this variable in your Twitter API call
 // ...
 // Make sure you assign your display content to the page by returning a variable
 return $page;
}
```